# Nestjs Typeorm query still using 'postgres' database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

When I try to query using `repository` for login api, I receive this error

```
QueryFailedError: relation "user" does not exist
```

After debuging, I realize the `nestjs` still using database with name "postgres". eventhough I set my database name in my `.env` as "nestjs". (I can confirm because when I migrate and seed the database "postgres" the login function works)

```
DB_TYPE=postgres
DB_HOST=db
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=postgres
DB_NAME=nestjs
DB_NAME_TEST=nestjs_test
DB_PORT=5432
```

All my migration and seed process already using database "nestjs". Below is my files to configure my database connection

`configuration.ts`

```js
import { registerAs } from '@nestjs/config';

export default registerAs('database', () => ({
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  user: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  name: process.env.DB_NAME,
  nameTest: process.env.DB_NAME_TEST,
  port: process.env.DB_PORT,
}));
```

`database/config.service.ts`

```js
...
get name(): string {
    return this.configService.get<string>(
      this.configService.get<string>('app.env') === 'test'
        ? 'database.nameTest'
        : 'database.name',
    );
  }
...
```

`database/config.migration.ts`

```js
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies';

export = {
  type: process.env.DB_TYPE,
  host: process.env.DB_HOST,
  port: +process.env.DB_PORT,
  username: process.env.DB_USER,
  password: process.env.DB_PASS,
  database:
    process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test'
      ? process.env.DB_NAME_TEST
      : process.env.DB_NAME,
  entities: [__dirname + '/../../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
  migrations: [__dirname + '/../../database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
  cli: {
    migrationsDir: __dirname + '/../../database/migrations',
  },
  extra: {
    charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
  },
  synchronize: false,
  logging: true,
  keepConnectionAlive: true,
  namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
};
```

`database/provider.module.ts`

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TypeOrmModule, TypeOrmModuleOptions } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { SnakeNamingStrategy } from 'typeorm-naming-strategies';
import { DatabaseConfigModule } from '../../config/database/config.module';
import { DatabaseConfigService } from '../../config/database/config.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
      imports: [DatabaseConfigModule],
      inject: [DatabaseConfigService],
      useFactory: async (
        service: DatabaseConfigService,
      ): Promise<TypeOrmModuleOptions> => ({
        type: service.type,
        host: service.host,
        port: service.port,
        username: service.user,
        password: service.password,
        name: service.name,
        entities: [__dirname + '/../../**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
        migrations: [__dirname + '/../../database/migrations/*{.ts,.js}'],
        cli: {
          migrationsDir: __dirname + '/../../database/migrations',
        },
        extra: {
          charset: 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        },
        synchronize: false,
        logging: true,
        keepConnectionAlive: true,
        namingStrategy: new SnakeNamingStrategy(),
      }),
    }),
  ],
})
export class DatabaseProviderModule {}
```

And here is my databases:

[image]

If you guys need more file for information please let me know. I'm new to nestjs and typeorm, So please tell me what's wrong with my code. Thank you!

Comment: Please delete `dist` folder and run your project again, and give me feedback

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi still gives me the same error :'(

Comment: If you pass the config manually it works correctly? for example:  `name: "nestjs"`

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi no different :'(

Comment: can you give me the github repository to run your code on my system?

Comment: @MohammadYaserAhmadi So its my stupid fault I use `name` property instead of `database` in my provider module. Thanks for trying to answer my question btw :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TypeormModule has the database property which provides the database name. You are using name in **provider.module.ts**:

- **Wrong**  name : databaseName
- **Right**  database : databaseName

```
TypeOrmModule.forRootAsync({
  useFactory: () => ({
    type: 'mysql',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 3306,
    username: 'root',
    password: 'root',
    database: 'test',
    entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],
    synchronize: true,
  }),
});
```

Comment: OMG, how can I not see this OTL. Thanks sir!

Comment: Any time sir ...